# Scipy.Optimize Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to optimize the parameters of a model I have built. Its a very simple model based predicting water runoff of a mountain. Part of a university coursework:

```
def model(params, snowProportion,temperature):
    '''
    Calculates predicted runoff.
    '''
    K = params[0]
    p = params[1]
    tempThresh = params[2]
    meltDays = np.where(temperature > tempThresh)[0]
    accum = snowProportion*0.
    for d in meltDays:
        water = K * snowProportion[d]
        n = np.arange(len(snowProportion)) - d
        m = p ** n
        m[np.where(n<0)]=0
        accum += m * water
    np.savetxt('2005predicted.dat', accum)

params = [2000, 0.96, 9]
```

I was told to use scipy.optimize.fmin_cg;

so I presume I do something along the lines of:

```
x = scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(model, params, args=[snowProportion, temperature])
```

I keep getting errors along the lines of:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

So then I presumed I needed them to be in lists - but i got the same problem:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I want to get better estimates of the params. SnowProportion and temperature are of the shape (365,)

RMSE:

import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

```
def RMSE(params,temperature, snowProportion):
    '''
    Calculates the RMSE of a model from measured and predicted.
    '''
    measured = np.loadtxt('/home/david/Documents/HydroM/runoff2005.dat')
    K = params[0]
    p = params[1]
    tempThresh = params[2]
    meltDays = np.where(temperature > tempThresh)[0]
    predicted = snowProportion*0.
    for d in meltDays:
        water = K * snowProportion[d]
        n = np.arange(len(snowProportion)) - d
        m = p ** n
        m[np.where(n<0)]=0
        predicted += m * water
    err = np.sqrt((measured - predicted) ** 2).mean()
    return err
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to [scipy.optimize.fmin_cg](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cg) -- named `model` in your code -- should represent the function that you want to minimize (**presumably the error of your models estimates with the given set of parameters compared to some reference values**...).
Specifically it should be a function that **returns a scalar value**.
The algorithm needs to know how 'well' the model performs with a given set of parameters.

Comment: Okay, so the function should be like a RMSE (Root mean square error). See change to code, to output mean RMSE.

Comment: @DavidColpey Do you get still errors? In principle it should work now (I didn't check the underlying logic). Your code still has significant 'design problems' which I'm going to address in my updated answer...

Comment: Yea it worked, but nothing changed. Parameters stayed the same.

Comment: @DavidColpey what are datatypes, dims of snowProportion, temperature?? can you explain what youre doing inside the for-loop?

Comment: params are a list: [2000, 0.96, 9], SnowProportion and temperature are numpy.ndarray shape (365,). Thanks

Comment: so `p` is 0.96, right? how does `m = p ** n` work? `n` will be a ndarray, right?

Comment: yea thats p, its a decay function. so if water on day x is 1, water on day x + 1 is p, day x+2 is p**2. and yea, m is a list.

Comment: I used scipy.optimize.fmin_powell instead, and it seems to be giving better results. The parameters change.

Comment: David Colpey: did scipy.optimize.fmin_powell  gave u correct result?